# PHP bring an array takes so long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm using an array of 23k of rows of two columns name,id. `$information['localidades']` then I have an array of 23 rows `($information['provincias'])` that matches several rows of the 23k by foreign key.

The thing is that the page takes so long to load the 23k of rows, like 20 seconds, there is any way to make it faster?

i used a jQuery with AJAX to bring each selection of the 23 rows to bring the dependences of the 23k but I want to do it by jQuery without AJAX.

```
   <select name="provincia" class="form-control" id="provincias">
                                                <option value="">Seleccione Provincia</option>
                                                <?php
                                                foreach ($information['provincias'] as $provincia) {
                                                    echo '<option value="' . $provincia['id'] . '">' . $provincia['nombre'] . '</option>';
                                                }
                                                ?>
                                            </select>


   <select name="localidad" class="form-control" id="localidades_select" >
                                                <option>Capital Federal</option>
                                            </select>

 <script>
                $("#provincias").change(function() {
                    var provincia_id = $(this).val();
                    var localidades = new Array();
                    localidades = <?php echo json_encode($information['localidades']); ?>;
                    $('#localidades_select').find('option').remove().end();
                    $.each(localidades, function(key, valor) {
                        if (valor.id_provincia == provincia_id) {
                            $("#localidades_select").append('<option value="' + valor.id + '">' + valor.nombre + '</option>');
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Why would you need to load 23k values?

Comment: where do these 23k rows come from?

Comment: NEVER LOAD A 23K-ITEM ARRAY INTO A WEB PAGE!

Comment: I would use some kind of caching strategy, for example pull the data you need when you need it and then save that in an array so if you need it again you wont have to pull it again.   I do this with auto complete fields all the time.

Comment: Can you somehow load it as a string? If you know that it will appear in an `option`-element, then perhaps you can ATTEMPT to store it as several `option`-elements in a string. Although really, it's a lot of data to handle, so don't expect something magical... (really though, I wouldn't advice you to do any of this)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or PDO. You are using Javascript to inject 23,000 nodes in the DOM. And you don't even cache parent node.

Comment: I know that seems ridiculous to load 23k of items in php array but i just want it to know if you have another idea than ajax.


maybe load it as string and then with jquery make explodes ??

Comment: I'll try to explain better. PHP has no particular problem with 23k arrays and you can easily verify that with your browser's console (find the "Net" or "Network" tab). Some test code with a **1 million** item array runs in 1.69 seconds in my (rather old) PC. But once PHP completes the page the browser is asked to perform extremely heavy HTML manipulations with code that is not particularly optimised (for instance, `$("#localidades_select")` never changes but you make jQuery recalculate it inside a loop). That's why I removed the PHP tag: it's not the PHP side what needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

23k DOM nodes will of course make rendering of the web page slow. It is not the actual generation of HTML from PHP that takes time (should be less than 2 seconds) - it is the time that the **browser uses to render the page** that is the bottleneck here.

I don't think your approach is great to this. You'll need some kind of lazy-loading via AJAX. Why not have an autocomplete textfield, where the user writes the first few character, and then load the matching rows into a suggestion box? There are plenty of solutions for that.

Try looking at [Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/).

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience, huge `<select>` controls are extremely slow to manipulate with JavaScript. Older Internet Explorer versions, in particular, are simply painful to work with.

Some tips:

- Avoid individual node handling. Instead, generate HTML markup and insert it at once with `.innerHTML`.
- Don't recalculate static stuff. For instance, `$("#localidades_select")` will never change so you can run it on page load and store the result in a variable.
- Try alternative data structures. For instance, if you group `$information['localidades']` by province you don't need `if (valor.id_provincia == provincia_id) {` inside the loop.
- Do as much as possible in PHP. For instance, you can try generating the complete HTML markup  on the server, rather than a mere array with raw data.
- Test in several browsers. Code that`s acceptable in browser A might take down browser B.

With some heavy optimisation you can probably reduce time to a few seconds, which is still slow but somehow usable anyway, but it's never going to be as fast as AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

By providing a php script to do more to the web page makes it slow to load, as the time taken to create the response will be great. Make sure all pages of your site loads faster.

even i had to use ajax for this case seriously. In case of rows keeps on increasing in the database the time to load also increased and
if you change mind of using ajax then fetch both data ie the foreign key and the data as a single query to make it more faster.